# Delete Duplicate Contacts from DB, but out of the Grouped Duplicates always keep primary

Tags: sql, duplicates

I am trying to figure out how to delete all duplicate contacts for each Customer based on the same First and Last name. I am aware that I must group by FirstName, LastName, and CustomerID but can't figure out: Out of each group how do I make sure I don't delete the duplicate set to Primary.

I know it will have something to do with making the primary one the first one in the group and then delete everything in each group except Row #1.

Here is what I have:

```
 Select *
 FROM CustomerContacts
 WHERE CustomerContactID NOT IN
 (
  SELECT MAX(CustomerContactID)
  FROM CustomerContacts
  GROUP BY ContactFirstName, ContactLastName, CustomerID
 )
```

Comment: How do you identify the "Primary" contact?  Your SQL doesn't provide any hints on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete everything except the one with the largest id, then the following is "conceptually" what you want to do:

```
delete from CustomerContacts
    where CustomerContractsId <> (select max(CustomerContactId)
                                  from CustomerContacts cc2
                                  where cc2.ContactFirstName = CustomerContacts.ContactFirstName and
                                        cc2.ContactLastName = CustomerContacts.ContactLastName and
                                        cc2.CustomerId = CustomerContacts.CustomerId
                                 );
```

Although this is standard SQL, some databases might have slightly different syntax for this.

EDIT (based on comment):

The following gets the id when `primary` is true or, if there is none, then the largest id:

```
delete from CustomerContacts
    where CustomerContractsId <> (select coalesce(max(case when primary then CustomerContactId end), max(CustomerContactId))
                                  from CustomerContacts cc2
                                  where cc2.ContactFirstName = CustomerContacts.ContactFirstName and
                                        cc2.ContactLastName = CustomerContacts.ContactLastName and
                                        cc2.CustomerId = CustomerContacts.CustomerId
                                 );
```

Comment: I am not sure if this solves my problem, please correct me if I am wrong. Out of the grouped duplicates I want to make sure to keep the one that is set to Primary=True rather than any of the others. If none of the duplicates are set as Primary=True then it doesn't matter which one is saved out of the duplicates. So out of the duplicates I want to save one of them, but if one of them is Primary=True then that one takes priority.